# Angular 6 - Router can't navigate to next page

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I have a method for authentification user before he opens any component.
When I receive isAuthorized from service, I simply need to forward a user to component he requested. In my case, I stay on the same page, the app works normally no errors, no logs to trace this problem, it simply stays on the page. Can anyone tell me what I do wrong?

```
 AuthUser() {
    let auth = new Authorize();
    auth.Credentials.CredentialsData1 = this.email;
    auth.Credentials.CredentialsData2 = this.password;
    auth.ResourceId = this.authGard.requestedComponentID;

    this.http.post(this.appGlobal.BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS + 'api/AppServer/Authorize', auth).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res['IsAuthorized'] == true)
        this.router.navigate([this.authGard.requestedComponent]);
      else this.router.navigate(['auth/unauthorized']);
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: you try to pass the `component` into your `nagivate()` method. you need to pass the `component route` into this methode..

Comment: No, it just a string

Comment: but `FluelDashboard` is your component name or not ?

Comment: what URL is generated after that navigate?

Comment: FluelDashboard is URL, the place where I want to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently helped out someone on my team with a similar issue.

I'm assuming that the component in "FuelDashboard" is protected via an authentication check.

However, I'm not seeing you saving the res['IsAuthorized'] response.

Q) Does the component in "FuelDashboard" check for authentication?

Q) Does an unauthorized request return the user to the login page?

Possible answer-  You will have to save the response ( res['IsAuthorized'] ) into a persistent location so that FuelDashboard can check if the user is authenticated.

Comment: This is cool, you open my eyes with question num 1. When I open FuelDashboard I have auth check, and that made a problem. I have solution now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Is your route FuelDashboard? I believe you are getting the component name and not the route name from the this.authGuard.requestedComponent and not the route you created at your app.routing.module.ts or whatever routing you opted in.

Comment: I know you don't have enough points to comment, but in the meanwhile don't post comments as answers please